# swapping of numbers using index in java is not working

Tags: java

```
    package dspermutation;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DSPermutation {
        String s;
        char[] c;
        int n;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DSPermutation ds=new DSPermutation();
            ds.input();
        }

        private void input() {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the string");
            s=sc.next();
            c=s.toCharArray();
            n=c.length;
            permutation(c,n-1,0);
        }

        private void permutation(char[] cc,int nn,int ii) {
            if(ii==nn)
            {
               System.out.println(cc);
            }
            else
            {
                for(int j=ii;j<=nn;j++)
                {
                    swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);
                    permutation(cc,nn,ii+1);
                    swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);
                }
            }    
        }

        private void swap(char p, char c0) {
            int x=s.indexOf(p);
            int y=s.indexOf(c0);
           /*1*/ char temp=c[x];
           /*2*/c[x]=c[y];
           /*3*/c[y]=temp;

           /*c[x]=c0;
            c[y]=p;*/         
        }   
    }
```

The above program is for printing all permutations of a given string.The result is coming true but in swap() method if i replace line 1,2,3(written in comment) by logic written in comment(after line 1,2,3) then answer comes wrong. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Your code doesn't work correctly either way.

Comment: @Kushagra Sinha Could you explain the difference between the correct and incorrect ouput. Why is the another one incorrect(your expectation Vs actual)?

Comment: correct output is the combination of all permutations and wrong answer is abc
abc
acb
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is assuming `c[x] == p` and `c[y] == c0`. But the indexes `x` and `y` are derived from the *immutable* string `s`, which doesn't reflect the values in `c` in its shuffled state.

Comment: can you please give me some more explanation?

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say.But above program is giving redundant result if length of string is 4(abcd).why is it so?

Comment: @KushagraSinha If you want to see the exact process, step through it in a debugger. Keep in mind what I said, that the other way also incorrectly produce duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping values of character array using `immutable` string's position (i.e String always holds the same initial values). To make your commented code work you have to add this `s = String.valueOf(c);`at the end of `swap` function.

```
private void swap(char p, char c0) {
    int x = s.indexOf(p);
    int y = s.indexOf(c0);

    // char temp = c[x];
    // c[x] = c[y];
    // c[y] = temp;

    c[y] = p;
    c[x] = c0;

    s = String.valueOf(c);


}
```

Comment: But what is the difference occurs when we use a third variable ''temp'' which gives us correct result?

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say.But above program is giving redundant result if length of string is 4(abcd).why is it so?

Comment: It is showing redundant result because string is not getting updated and you swap based on the character position of the string. Replace your swap function with given one and it will work fine. I don't see any redundant result with above swap function.