# Permutation of String in java

Tags: java

The below code gives redundant permutation values in case of string having length 4.But if we replace line 1,2,3 of swap function by the code written below it(in comment) then no redundant result get printed.Why could this is happening?

```
package dspermutation;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class DSPermutation {
String s;
char[] c;
int n;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DSPermutation ds=new DSPermutation();
        ds.input();
    }

    private void input() {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        s=sc.next();
        c=s.toCharArray();
        n=c.length;
        permutation(c,n-1,0);
    }

    private void permutation(char[] cc,int nn,int ii) {
        if(ii==nn)
        {
          System.out.println(cc);

        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=ii;j<=nn;j++)
            {
                swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);
                permutation(cc,nn,ii+1);
                swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);
            }
        }

    }

    private void swap(char p, char c0) {
        int x=s.indexOf(p);
        int y=s.indexOf(c0);
        /*1*/char temp=c[x];
        /*2*/c[x]=c[y];
        /*3*/c[y]=temp;

       /*c[x]=c0;
       c[y]=p;
       s=String.valueOf(c)*/



    }   
}
```

Comment: "the no redundant result get printed" - the what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swapping of numbers using index in java is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663715/swapping-of-numbers-using-index-in-java-is-not-working)

Comment: Consider providing example data. And: your variable names are pretty much horrible.

Comment: Please rephrase what are you asking about...

Comment: With those lines `1,2,3` are you still doing `s=String.valueOf(c)`? Because you should, if you don't then all the swapping has no effect.

Comment: sorry the statement is "then no redundant result get printed"

Comment: redundant result:
abcd
abdc
acbd
adbc
adcb
acdb
cdba
dcba
cabd
cdba
bdca
cdba
bcda
acdb
acdb
abdc
acdb
abdc
cadb
cbda
acdb
abdc
acdb
abdc

Comment: can anybody explain the reason?

Answer (score 0):

> Call-by-reference

```
{      
        private void permutation(char[] cc,int nn,int ii) {
        ...
        ...
        for(int j=ii;j<=nn;j++)
        {
            swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);

            // Here you are passing reference of cc[ii] to swap method.
            // and  then if you remove the comment from swap method, 
            // cc[ii] and cc[j] are getting exchanged from that method.


            permutation(cc,nn,ii+1);
            swap(cc[ii],cc[j]);
        }
    }
 ...
 ...
      private void swap(char p, char c0) {

      int x=s.indexOf(p);
      int y=s.indexOf(c0);
      char temp=c[x];
      c[x]=c[y];
      c[y]=temp;

      } 
}
```

Comment: sir can you please explain it by giving example?